# Ionic exclude google photos from camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I'm using ionic 3, I want to select an image from my gallery and crop the image, I've successfully created this, but a problem occurs when I choose google photos instead of a gallery, the crop editor didn't show up and the image become blur. Therefore I just want to use Gallery option and excluding the google photos option.

[image]

```
        options.sourceType = this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {  
          this.base64Image = imageData.replace('file://','');
          // for cropping image
          let modal = this.modal.create('CanvaseditPage',{data:"data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData});
          modal.present();
        }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this a known issue in Cordova ( at least, I saw it in their public JIRA account as a bug report ). But nothing seems to be getting done about it.

So, I found a workaround. I ended up not using Ionic’s cropping tool at all. Instead, I used a plugin called Cropperjs ( https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/ 13 ). I got a lot of information on how to implement it from this thread ( Image cropping plugin 13 ). I pulled my implementation together from a few of the posts in there.

First, I created a modal called CropImageModal and I just launch that modal once I get the uncropped image from the camera.

**Here is the code for the modal window:**

```
import Cropper from ‘cropperjs’;
import { NavParams, ViewController } from ‘ionic-angular’;
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from ‘@angular/core’;

@Component({
selector: ‘crop-image-modal’,
template: <div padding text-center> <div><img [src]="imageToCrop" (load)="imageLoaded()" #imageSrc ></div> </div> <p text-center> <button ion-button border round outline (click)="cancel()">CANCEL</button> <button ion-button border round outline (click)="crop()">CROP</button> </p>
})
export class CropImageModal {
    @ViewChild(‘imageSrc’) imageInput: ElementRef;
    public imageToCrop: any;
    public cropper: Cropper;

    constructor(public params: NavParams, public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
        this.imageToCrop = params.get('imageToCrop');
    }

    imageLoaded() {
        console.log("starting Cropper... "); 
        this.cropper = new Cropper(this.imageInput.nativeElement, {
            aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
            dragMode: 'move',
            modal: true,
            guides: true,
            highlight: false,
            background: true,
            autoCrop: true,
            autoCropArea: 0.9,
            responsive: true,
            crop: (e:Cropper.CropperCustomEvent) => {}
        });
    }

    cancel() {
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss(undefined);
    }

    crop() {
        let croppedImage:string = this.cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
            width: 500,
            height: 500
        }).toDataURL('image/jpeg', (100 / 100)); // 100 / 100 = photo quality

        this.viewCtrl.dismiss( 
            { 
                image: croppedImage
            } 
        );
    }
}
```

**And here is all of the relevant code from my page file to launch the cropping modal:**

```
//Import cropper modal
import {CropImageModal} from “…/crop-image/crop-image-modal”;

//Launches the native device’s camera.

takePicture( ){
    if( this.platform.is(‘cordova’) ){
        let cameraOptions = {
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            encodingType: 0,
            quality: 100,
            targetWidth: 500,
            targetHeight: 500,
            correctOrientation: true,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
            allowEdit: false
        }
        Camera.getPicture(cameraOptions).then((imageData) => {
            // imageData is the URI for the file
            this.imageToCrop = imageData;
            this.launchCropModal();
        }, (err) => {
            console.log( 'Error creating image: ', err);
        });
    }
}

//Displays a modal window for the user to crop their selected image.
launchCropModal(){
    let params = {
        imageToCrop: this.imageToCrop
    };

    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(CropImageModal, params);
    modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
        if (data) {
            this.childService.child.avatar = this.avatar = data.image;
            this.uploadAvatar();
        }
    });

    modal.present();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this cropping code in ionic v1 I don't know how much it's useful to you. so I am just sharing my code with you so that you will get an idea.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(gotPhotoLibrary, onError, {
                                    quality: 90,
                                    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                                    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                                    allowEdit: true,
                                    targetWidth: 200, //what widht you want after capaturing
                                    targetHeight: 200
                                });
```

I use plugins.crop.promise plugin to crop the image

```
function gotPhotoLibrary(imageUri) {
                // window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageUri, function (fileEntry) {
                var options = {
                    quality: 150,
                    widthRatio: 1,
                    heightRatio: 1,
                    targetWidth: 600,
                    targetHeight: 600
                };
                plugins.crop.promise(imageUri, options)
                .then(function success(newPath) {
                    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(newPath, function (fileEntry) {
                        fileEntry.file(function (fileObj) {
                            if (fileObj.size <= 153600) {
                                var reader = new FileReader();
                                reader.onload = function () {
                                    var dataURL = reader.result;
                                    self.ProfilePic = dataURL;
                                    setProfilePic();
                                };
                                reader.readAsDataURL(fileObj);
                            }
                            else {
                                //  alert("Please upload image less then 150KB");
                                alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                                    title: 'Upload image failed!',
                                    template: 'Please upload image less then 150KB!'
                                });
                            }

                            console.log("Size = " + fileObj.size);
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
```